# Error al usar el metodo URL

Tags: javascript, html

//Buenas tardes gente, tengo el siguiente codigo

```
$("#file").on('change', function () {

    var dato = $("#file").files;

    var creat = `<div style="background-image: url(${URL.createObjectURL(dato)});" class="cont-img previews">`;
    $("#previews").html(creat);

});
```

//Este es mi html

```
<form id="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple>
           <button type="submit" id="public" disabled="true" class=" env btn btn-primary">subir</button>
    <label class="label" for="file">
        Subir imagen 
    </label>
</form>
<div class="views-previews" id="previews"></div>
```

//Quiero hacer una pequeña previsualizacion de una imagen antes de subirla al servidor, no me llevo mucho con el temas de las imagenes, cuando se termina de ejecutar el codigo, la consola del nevegador me muestra el siguiente error `Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.`, me pueden ayudar? muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos cosas:

1. Tienes que buscar la imagen en el índice `0` del input file.
2. Tienes un poco de lío sobre el contenedor donde quieres mostrar el preview.

Si quieres mostrarlo en el contenedor `blah` basta con esto:

```js
$("#file").on('change', function() {
  var src = `${window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])}`;
  $('#blah').prop('src', src);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple>
  <button type="submit" id="public" disabled="true" class=" env btn btn-primary">subir</button>
  <label class="label" for="file">
        Subir imagen 
    </label>
</form>
<div class="views-previews" id="previews"></div>
<img id="blah" alt="your image" width="100" height="100" />
```

Por el contrario, si lo quieres mostrar dentro de un `div` que esté en el contenedor `previews` tienes que corregir un poco el lío que tienes creando el `div`:

```js
$("#file").on('change', function() {
  var divImg = `<div><img  class="cont-img previews" src="${window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])}"/></div>`;
  $("#previews").html(divImg);
});
```

```css
.previews{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple>
  <button type="submit" id="public" disabled="true" class=" env btn btn-primary">subir</button>
  <label class="label" for="file">
        Subir imagen 
    </label>
</form>
<div class="views-previews" id="previews"></div>
<img id="blah" alt="your image" width="100" height="100" />
```

Comment: tu solución es mas que perfecta, pero al querer ingresar dos imagenes no puedo, yo quiero que el usuario ingrese un maximo de 4 imagenes nomas

Comment: @Enzo en ese caso sólo tendrías que recorrer `this.files` para obtener las imágenes por ejemplo o implementarlo de otra forma. Pero debes indicar en qué momento quisieras mostrar los previews.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, saludos.